# Rails 2.3-style plugins and deprecation warnings running task in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm upgrading to Rails 3.2, and running rake db:migrate gives me several errors of the form:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from  at /app/Rakefile:7)

What's perplexing is that my `vendor/plugins` directory is empty -- is there another plugins directory that it's referencing?

Comment: Was even more preplexing for me as I DID have stuff there, but after removing it still go the error from Heroku! Great question, great answer

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Are you using Heroku?

> Heroku will inject plugins in Rails 3.x applications ..
>   To avoid this
>   injection in Rails 3, include the rails_12factor gem in your
>   application. ([Heroku Ruby Support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#injected-plugins) 2013-10-26)

The rails_12factor gem is also required in rails 4.

> If this gem is not present in your application, you will receive a
>   warning while deploying, and your assets and logs will not be
>   functional. ([Rails 4 on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4) 2013-10-26)

As recently as 2013-08, heroku always injected plugins in rails 3 apps, even apps with the recommended gems.   This was an issue with the ruby buildpack, and was fixed by [PR 11](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/pull/11), merged on 2013-08-06.

Comment: Yep, I realize that all the warnings came from my Heroku scripts and logs.  I'll assume that (a) it's the plugin injections and (b) that the Heroku team will fix this before it becomes an actual problem.

Comment: Im a newbie and i am a little stuck on how i edit railties-3.2.0. Can you please help.

Comment: @vezu I recommend you don't start. This was something that used to be common before we started using bundler, but right now it's unlikely to work, and will probably just break stuff.

Comment: @MatthewRudy do you have any suggestions. I email heroku yesterday but no luck.

Comment: I tried adding an initializer https://gist.github.com/1709421 but it doesnt work (I guess plugins are loaded earlier than app initializers). My suggestion is dont worry... its just noise.

Comment: a year later... no change from heroku.

Comment: And rails 4.0 is almost upon us. From: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/2/25/Rails-4-0-beta1/ 

"Hot on the heels of the first production version of Ruby 2.0 comes 
the first beta version of Rails 4.0. The two form a great pair and 
are already running in production on a number of applications, 
including Basecamp Breeze. In fact, Ruby 2.0 is the preferred Ruby 
to use with Rails 4.0."

Heroku is not having a good month however, so we'll see how much bandwidth they have for this issue.

Answer (score 12):

You can try

```
::ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true
```

in your `production.rb` since it's just noise.

Comment: Ideally one would only suppress this particular warning, do you know if that's possible?

Comment: if you do it in production.rb you should see the errors in development - if all else fails set the opposite in development.rb

Comment: Not suppressing the warnings for me

Comment: One hack to suppress just this warning is to add the following to application.rb: `ActiveSupport::Deprecation.behavior = Proc.new { |msg, stack| $stderr.puts msg unless msg =~ /You have Rails 2.3-style plugins/ }`

Answer (score 8):

in config/environment.rb add:

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true
```

before initializing rails, like so:

```
# Load the rails application                                                                                                                                             
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true                                                                                                                               

# Initialize the rails application                                                                                                                                       
MyApp::Application.initialize!
```

Similarly to disable warnings in rake tasks insert the silencing config near the top of your Rakefile:

```
# Load the rails application                                                                                                                                             
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true                                                                                                                           

# Initialize the rails application                                                                                                                                       
MyApp::Application.initialize!
```

You can optionally wrap this in a block to only silence in production:

```
if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "production"
  ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true
end
```

Comment: Hmm.. this did not remove my warning either.

Comment: I initially passed up this answer b/c of the above two comments, but it in fact *did* work for me.  Running Rails 3.2.6.  YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

The best approach I have found is documented [here](http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/converting-a-more-complex-rails-2-3-style-plugin-to-non-deprecated-under-rails-3-2/). This is assuming you searched and found this question because you **do** have old-style plugins.

I went with the **Make it not a gem at all** part, because I needed to be able to turn plugins on/off during my capistrano deployment, based on what flavor of the app I was deploying. Before I used config.plugins to specify what plugin to use. With this approach I'm using a "require" on config.before_configuration instead.

Comment: +1. I ended up using the [Matt Coneybeare gives you a nice walkthrough](http://matt.coneybeare.me/how-to-convert-simple-rails-23-style-plugins/) link (found in the page @yuri linked) to convert my simple rails 2.3 plugins to 3.2. I liked this solution because it didn't just silence the warnings, it actually fixes them.

Answer (score 1):

Just put following monkey patch into `/lib/silence_heroku_warnings.rb`

```
module Rails
  class Plugin < Engine

    alias :not_silenced_initialize :initialize

    def initialize(root)
      ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silence{ self.send :not_silenced_initialize, root }
    end

  end
end
```

and require it in `config/application.rb` just after requiring Rails:

```
require 'rails/all'
require File.expand_path('../../lib/silence_heroku_warnings', __FILE__)
```

All deprecations from 2.x-style plugins should be silenced. Other deprecations will show up.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way than just silencing warnings, here is what you can do.

For the logger injection you can try to use [Heroku's new gem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4#logging-and-assets) that [Jared Beck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567762/jared-beck) mentioned in [his reply above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9042604/459863).

What we did instead is this:

You can inhibit Heroku from injecting its own plugins if you have a directory by the same name in your `vendor/plugins` folder. The folder just needs to exist. Heroku then will not inject its plugin, and if there is no code, Rails won't object with deprecation warnings. We just put a readme file explaining this into:

```
vendor/plugins/rails_log_stdout/readme.md
```

The purpose of Heroku's injected plugin for logging is to turn on Heroku-style logging (it requires logs to be sent to STDOUT, not to a file). To get that back, we did what I described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17309931/459863). Tweaks to Heroku's default behaviors were needed for Unicorn anyway, so we got two birds in one stone.

Comment: Better add a blank file named `.gitkeep` to vendor/plugins/rails_log_stdout

`.gitkeep` is a convention to keep an empty directory when using git.

Comment: Fair enough, I prefer a little more verbosity as to why, that's why I liked the readme approach. You're right though that `.gitkeep` is a convention.

Answer (score 0):

The new way of silencing deprecation notices is:

```
config.active_support.deprecation = :silence
```

in your `config/environments/production.rb` file.

Comment: Also not suppressing the warnings for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Heroku has finally addressed this.

```
   Injecting plugin 'rails_log_stdout'
   Injecting plugin 'rails3_serve_static_assets'
   Add 'rails_12factor' gem to your Gemfile to skip plugin injection
```