# Rails 3.2, Heroku deprecation warning - "DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, carrierwave

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Rails 2.3-style plugins and deprecation warnings running task in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027403/rails-2-3-style-plugins-and-deprecation-warnings-running-task-in-heroku)

A few days ago I decided to upgrade my Rails 3.1 app to Rails 3.2. Everything works well on my local machine, both in production and development environments.  When I push the app to Heroku I get an error and the app crashes.

**Error message:**

```
2012-01-31T11:36:18+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-01-31T11:36:18+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Thin
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:25836
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant CarrierWave (NameError)
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-01-31T11:36:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
```

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'devise'
gem "cancan"
gem "friendly_id", "~> 4.0.0.beta14"
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'ancestry'
gem "fog"
gem 'dragonfly', '~>0.9.9'
gem 'rack-cache', :require => 'rack/cache'
gem 'tinymce-rails'

group :development, :test do
    gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11"
    gem 'sqlite3'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.2.3"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.2.1"
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  
end


# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', '0.8.2', :require => false
end
```

I emailed Heroku support and the response was

> Hello -
>
> The last line is pointing to an issue with Fog - a library used to communicate with cloud providers such as Amazon.
>
> Will you ensure the 'fog' gem has been added to your app?

I am 100% sure the gem is there as you can see my gem file.Then again another response

> Are you able to reproduce this issue locally in 'production' mode?
>
> If you add the 'thin' gem to your Gemfile, you can simulate the Heroku environment with 'bundle exec thin start -e production'
>
> January 30, 2012 11:43 am

I had already done this and everything works on on my local machine. I am a little lost as to the solution. I read this [Rails 2.3-style plugins and deprecation warnings running task in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027403/eliminating-rails-2-3-style-plugins-and-deprecation-warnings) and I was discouraged from trying that hack as a solution.  As another solution I decided to downgrade my app to Rails 3.1 and the issue still persists. What am I missing here?

I suspect that this came from Carrierwave gem which I have removed along with uploader. But Heroku still refers to it. There is nothing in my config file about carrier-wave.

Comment: You don't have the config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb file mentioned in the stack trace ?

Comment: No i don't,  i removed it when i removed the carrier_wave gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is nothing to do with plugins or Rails 3.2 from what I can see, they're deprecations.  It looks to me like you've uninstalled carrierwave incorrectly.

The error message states that you still have a `config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb` and that that is still trying to reference the missing CarrierWave object.

I would suggest ensuring that your carrierwave is properly removed, and also removed from git.

Comment: @Niel Middleton, i have checked a lot of times, That file doesn't exist on my config folder. It's like heroku is not updating my app.

Comment: Your error says otherwise.  Check that you've committed the deleted file and pushed that change to Heroku

Comment: I tried everything and the only thing solved the problem was precompiling my assets.