# removing rails plugins from project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, deprecated

I'm getting this deprecation error on my rails 3.2 project which I upgraded from a rails 3.1 project:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these  plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
```

I'm trying to get rid of this error, but I can't seem to find the plugin.  I have already deleted the plugin from vendor/plugins.

Comment: So your vendor/plugins directly is **completely** empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your vendor/plugins is completely empty, then I bet you're deploying to Heroku. As part of the deploy process, Heroku injects plugins into your application. Check out [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027403/eliminating-rails-2-3-style-plugins-and-deprecation-warnings) for an actual Heroku response to this issue.