# Specified sqlite3 for database adapter but gem is not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

I'm new to Rails and was trying to launch my server. Running the command `rails server` generated an error

> Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

I looked at many of these previous questions and none seems to solve it. Here is my Gemfile code

```
if RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/
   Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
   Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
end

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.0'

gem 'ey_config'
gem 'rails_autolink'
gem 'simple_form'

# Assets
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'uglifier'

platform :ruby do
   gem 'mysql2'
   gem 'pg'
   gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter', '3.0.0.beta2'
   gem 'sqlite3'

   gem 'newrelic_rpm'
   gem 'unicorn'
   gem 'puma'
   gem 'json'
   gem 'minitest'
   gem 'psych'
   gem 'racc'
end

platforms :jruby do
   ar_jdbc_version = '~> 1.3'
   gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', ar_jdbc_version
   gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter', ar_jdbc_version
   gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter', ar_jdbc_version
   gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter', ar_jdbc_version
   gem 'jdbc-mysql', :require => false
   gem 'jdbc-sqlite3', :require => false
   gem 'jdbc-postgres', :require => false

   gem 'jruby-openssl'
   gem 'trinidad'
end

platform :rbx do
   gem 'rubysl'
   gem 'rubysl-test-unit', :require => false
end

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
group :development, :test do
   gem 'tzinfo-data'
end
```

And here is my database.yml file

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
development:
   adapter: sqlite3
   database: db/development.sqlite3
   pool: 5
   timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
   adapter: sqlite3
   database: db/test.sqlite3
   pool: 5
   timeout: 5000

production:
   adapter: sqlite3
   database: db/production.sqlite3
   pool: 5
   timeout: 5000`
```

Here is the code in my rakefile:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'

Listr::Application.load_tasks

task :travis => ['db:create:all', 'db:migrate', :default]
```

It will be also appreciated for providing any explanation accompanying the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sqlite3 gem is not being loaded, because of where you've got it in the Gemfile. Take it out of `platform :ruby do` and place it outside of that block , May be right under `gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.0'`

Comment: @abhilash.reddy updated the code and now run `bundle update` which gives an error: `Cannot locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`

Comment: are you sure, You are in the root directory of the app? This error comes when you run bundle outside of the root directory

Comment: @abhilash.reddy sorry for this, I forgot I was not in the root directory of the app

Comment: now it says `Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development``what do I do?

Comment: Run "rake db:migrate"

Comment: Ok it says `No Rakefile found <looking for rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb`

Comment: Goto app root directory and search for `Rakefile`. If you don't find, It means the Rakefile might be missing and you need to create a new one. Todo so create a new file with name `Rakefile` without any extensions and paste this code `require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Blog::Application.load_tasks`

Comment: Replace `Blog` with your app name

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452701/ruby-on-rails-no-rakefile-found-error

Comment: `require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Rails.application.load_tasks` If my previous code for Rakefile doesn't work,use this instead

Comment: Hi, Let me know if this helped!!

Comment: @abhilash.reddy I have rakefile which looks like this: `# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'

Listr::Application.load_tasks

task :travis => ['db:create:all', 'db:migrate', :default]
`

Comment: try with renaming `Rakefile` to `rakefile.rb`

Comment: yeah, renamed `Rakefile` to `rakefile.rb` and now run `rake db:migrate` still says that they cannot find rakefile

Comment: Again make sure you are in root directory !! Looks like you are not !!

Comment: aww stupid me! now I think everything is fine, well, I think so, according to this image http://i.imgur.com/fhIur6Q.png

Answer (score 4):

Your sqlite3 gem is not being loaded in production, because of the version mismatch. so, update you `gemfile as gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.13'` it'll work. Keep it under `group :production, :test` It'll be good when you push your code to heroku.