# Rails app halting on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, heroku

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [eliminating Rails 2.3-style plugins and deprecation warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027403/eliminating-rails-2-3-style-plugins-and-deprecation-warnings)

I have an issue with a rails 3.2.8 app on Heroku (keilmiller.herokuapp.com).

`pg`, `thin` and `foreman` are required in my gemfile for production.

I am using the cedar stack.
I pushed my new app to heroku with `--force`.
I ran `heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE` to eliminate my old database.
Running `heroku run rake db:migrate`, or any other rake command yield an error.

*DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins!*

I do not have any rails plugins. I know I had an issue like this in the past, but I guess Heroku changed support to stack overflow. I can no longer view my old tickets with Heroku. Any help would be much appreciated.

Why is my App Halting?

EDIT: I just deleted my app from heroku and created another app with the cedar stack. Fresh start. Pushed my local app to heroku. I get an application error when trying to view the page, and I still get the plugin error when I try running a `heroku run rake` command.

Edit: I thought that there might be some sort of incompatibility with ruby versions. Log file has directory `from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1` but `heroku run "ruby -v"` yielded 1.9.2. I updated my gemfile to include ruby 1.9.3 and pushed to heroku. Heroku is indeed running 1.9.3 just like my local env, but the log it puts out is still the same.

Edit: I wiped out the db again, restarted the heroku app, and got a new log.

Edit: I had an issue with my carrierwave initializer. Fixed. Pushed. Posted new log. `/app/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:2:in`': uninitialized constant FoundationRailsHelper::FlashHelper (NameError)`Something is going on I think with this statement in my application helper`include FoundationRailsHelper::FlashHelper` using https://github.com/sgruhier/foundation_rails_helper It works perfectly in dev mode.

CURRENT LOG
-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

```
$ heroku logs
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:2:in `<module:ApplicationHelper>': uninitialized constant FoundationRailsHelper::FlashHelper (NameError)
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:135:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `modules_for_helpers'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:92:in `modules_for_helpers'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `map!'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:22:in `block in inherited'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:159:in `default_helper_module!'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:95:in `helper'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:22:in `class_eval'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:22:in `inherited'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:32:in `inherited'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:135:in `inherited'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `require'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-09-28T00:18:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-09-28T00:18:18+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-09-28T00:18:18+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-09-28T00:22:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-09-28T00:22:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 3734`
2012-09-28T00:22:14+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-09-28T00:22:14+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-09-28T00:22:14+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:2:in `<module:ApplicationHelper>': uninitialized constant FoundationRailsHelper::FlashHelper (NameError)
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `modules_for_helpers'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:135:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:22:in `class_eval'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:95:in `helper'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:22:in `block in inherited'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:159:in `default_helper_module!'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:22:in `inherited'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:92:in `modules_for_helpers'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `map!'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:32:in `inherited'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:135:in `inherited'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `require'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2012-09-28T00:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2012-09-28T00:22:17+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-09-28T00:22:17+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-09-28T00:27:50+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-09-28T00:27:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 55735`
```

**ANSWER**

For some reason, this thread is closed. I'm really not liking stack overflow. Anyways, the "answer" should be to move the gem out of the assets group. I put it there without thinking. Solved the issue. Now I know, if there is a warning about something not being initialized or missing, check to see if the gem is included in production.

Comment: Did you check to see what's in `vendor/plugins`?

Comment: This is not an error, it's just a warning that some library you are using (or maybe some of their dependencies) use old style plugins.

Comment: @Ken White I do not have any rails plugins. That folder is empty, sans a .gitkeep file.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, I think these warnings are keeping my app from launching.?

Comment: The linked question and it's answer specifically address this error and the folder being empty.

Comment: If your app isn’t launching, it must be something else – this warning doesn’t prevent an app from running.

Comment: What’s do you have at `/app/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:19`?

Comment: Looks to me like some kind of incompatibility between FoundationRailsHelper and Heroku.  It's happening in your initializers, as evidenced by the `/app/config/environment.rb:5` and `/app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1` buried in your stack trace.  I notice the author says it's tested on 3.1, but should work on Rails 3.0 ... No mention of 3.2  I'd see if you can get in touch with the author, or try doing just a plain vanilla `rails new testapp` and add in FoundationRailsHelper only and see if you can deploy that to another Heroku app.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @likethesky for your diagnosis. I'll try that out and see what's going on with the gem.

Comment: For some reason, this thread is closed. I'm really not liking stack overflow. Anyways, the "answer" should be to move the gem out of the assets group. I put it there without thinking. Solved the issue. Now I know, if there is a warning about something not being initialized or missing, check to see if the gem is included in production.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9042604/492404) definitely addresses fully your initial question regarding deprecation warnings from Heroku deployment.  Basically, just ignore these until Heroku decides to get around to updating them.

If you aren't getting those warnings on your local builds, then they're just older plugins that Heroku is using.

Comment: I have no issues locally. These warnings are halting my app I believe.? The app will not load. `heroku restart` yields no change.

Comment: Ah.  I would then delete the Heroku app and reinstall it.  You shouldn't have to `push --force` ... Also, those warnings will definitely *not* halt your app.  There's some other problem if it's halting.  Have you checked your logs?

Comment: Actually, the linked question is for exactly this situation. This question is a duplicate, and should be closed as one. Nice find. :-)

Comment: I think the OP is having further difficulties.  Keil Miller you should edit your question to ask what your real difficulty is, which is that your app is halting.  Or let this one get closed as duplicate and ask another question.

Comment: I forced the push because i wanted to replace the app with another one, but didn't want to set up a new "space" with heroku and have to go threw setting up my dns and such all over again. Original post edited.