# Rails deprecation warning for vendor/plugins when I don't have any

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [eliminating Rails 2.3-style plugins and deprecation warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027403/eliminating-rails-2-3-style-plugins-and-deprecation-warnings)

I get the following error when I do a `heroku run console`:

```
$ heroku run console
Running `console` attached to terminal... up, run.1
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out an d bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out an d bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.8)
irb(main):001:0>
```

However, the only file I have in vendor/plugins is `.gitkeep`:

```
$ ls -lha vendor/plugins/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    1 Scott    Administ        0 Sep  7 12:26 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 Scott    Administ        0 Sep  7 12:26 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 Scott    Administ        0 Sep  7 12:26 .gitkeep
```

I even tried removing the `.gitkeep` file and I still get the same deprecation warning. Do I have bad plugins? This is a relatively new Rails project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heroku injects old-style plugins to make your app work on their server (specifically to redirect logs to stdout, and to serve static assets from rails). Check the output from a `git push`... you'll see something like this

```
-----> Rails plugin injection
       Injecting rails_log_stdout
       Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
```

So it's not something you've done, and nor is it anything to worry about! These will work just fine on Rails 3.x and Heroku will no doubt work something out when Rails 4 is a bit more mature.