# DEPRECATION WARNING in heroku during deploying rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails 2.3-style plugins and deprecation warnings running task in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027403/rails-2-3-style-plugins-and-deprecation-warnings-running-task-in-heroku)

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support
 for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them i
n your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initial
izers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonr
ails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required
)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
```

shows 3 times, sometimes shows 2 times what it means? is there any special meaning?
**How to solve this problem for db:migrate**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku "injects" some plugins during slug compilation.

```
-----> Rails plugin injection
       Injecting rails_log_stdout
       Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
```

See [Rails 2.3-style plugins and deprecation warnings running task in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027403/rails-2-3-style-plugins-and-deprecation-warnings-running-task-in-heroku)