# Rails 2.3-style plugins: why the deprecation warnings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

While deploying to Heroku, I get a set of deprecation warnings about the vendor/plugins folder (see below).  Mine has a .gitkeep statement in it, and nothing else.  Is there anything I need to do?

```
2012-12-13T02:56:59+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-12-13T02:56:59+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-12-13T02:56:59+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 2.3-style plugins and deprecation warnings running task in Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027403/rails-2-3-style-plugins-and-deprecation-warnings-running-task-in-heroku)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku has already pointed this out and they are already working on it for Rails 4

Heroku works by injecting plugins and it causes this to happen

```
-----> Rails plugin injection
       Injecting rails_log_stdout
       Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
```

[Rails 2.3-style plugins and deprecation warnings running task in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027403/rails-2-3-style-plugins-and-deprecation-warnings-running-task-in-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed a workaround that Heroku has now.

```
   Injecting plugin 'rails_log_stdout'
   Injecting plugin 'rails3_serve_static_assets'
   Add 'rails_12factor' gem to your Gemfile to skip plugin injection
```