# How to purge Heroku-injected gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

During deployment [Heroku injects some plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027403/rails-2-3-style-plugins-and-deprecation-warnings-running-task-in-heroku)

```
-----> Rails plugin injection
       Injecting rails_log_stdout
       Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
```

..which are becoming deprecated

> DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in
>   vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails
>   4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/*

I have been using heroku some time ago (and the gems have been injected), but moved to a VPS solution, so I'm not using Heroku anymore. How do I purge the injected plugins from my app? In the end I want to get rid of these deprecation warnings.

Comment: They are injected at runtime and you do not need to worry about them if you are anyway not using heroku!

Comment: I'm not worrying about them, I just want them to be gone, so the deprecation message is gone.

Answer (score 0):

The gems are injected at Runtime – if you're using Heroku, you can't avoid them, unless you make a [custom buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#creating-a-buildpack).

If you're not using Heroku anymore, then how/where are you seeing this message?

Comment: I have been using heroku some time ago (and the gems have been injected), but moved to a VPS solution, so I'm not using Heroku anymore.

Comment: The gems are injected to your app on Heroku, at runtime. They aren't injected into your local code base. Those gems are only injected when the app is ran on Heroku. So, you shouldn't see those messages if you're not on Heroku, and if you are, then *you* have gems that are causing this, not gems injected by Heroku :D