# What's the "official" way to support Unicorn on Heroku and not lose logging?

Tags: logging, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, unicorn

We switched to Unicorn, but lost all app logging on Heroku. I googled around a bit and learned Heroku's Ruby buildpack installs a plugin "rails_log_stdout" which doesn't play nice with Unicorn. My guess would be this has something to do with the forking nature of Unicorn, but I didn't confirm that.

Various workarounds like https://gist.github.com/jamiew/2227268 where suggested. These strike me as dis-satisfying because they won't use the log levels defined in the Rails app or any tags, or logger formatting overrides, etc. It seemed a bit brute force to me. What's the "official" way to do this right?

Comment: I followed https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/2/27/unicorn_rails last night and I can see logs coming through just fine.

Comment: what version of rails and unicorn? I'm switched an app to Unicorn and still see my logs

Comment: We're using Rails 3.2.11 and Unicorn 4.6.2. I had to re-instantiate the logger inside the production.rb file. Then I got it to work.
Thanks for the link to the Heroku post. That was writter a few days after we did this, but we already had the basic structure and it doesn't say anything about logging.

Comment: @WolframArnold could you explain how you re-instantiated the logger in `production.rb`?

Comment: I'm going to add an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I've re-instantiated the logger to avoid losing logging levels or loggin tags. I had to do this separately in each environment file, `production.rb`, `staging.rb` (if you have it), etc.

```
MyApp::Application.configure do

  # ...

  logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger) if defined?(ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging)
  config.logger = logger
  log_level_env_override = Logger.const_get(ENV['LOG_LEVEL'].try(:upcase)) rescue nil
  config.logger.level = log_level_env_override || Logger.const_get(Rails.configuration.log_level.to_s.upcase)

  # ...

end
```

I'm not in love with this. I was hoping that there was something more elegant baked into Unicorn.