# Remote Heroku application crashes; local is fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I have a rails app that works locally (tested with `bundle exec`), but crashed on Heroku (Cedar stack). The configuration locally is identical to the remote, (both are using Postgres). The crash is actually rather perplexing to me, because the stack trace makes appears to be occurring within the Rails/Thin environment. The deprecation warning is equally perplexing, as there is nothing in my vendor/plugins directory!

```
Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 38427`
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/ and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/ and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:378:in `destroy': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /app/app/models/transcript.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/querying.rb:7:in `destroy'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /app/app/models/transcript.rb:4:in `<class:Transcript>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from config.ru:1:in `new'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
from config.ru:3:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
Process exited with status 1
State changed from starting to crashed
```

I have already run `rake db:reset` and `rake db:migrate` just to be sure that its not an issue with the database system.

Contents of transcript file:

```
class Transcript < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :grade, :hours

  belongs_to :student, class_name: 'User', dependent: destroy
  belongs_to :course
end
```

Comment: Did you mean `heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027403/rails-2-3-style-plugins-and-deprecation-warnings-running-task-in-heroku for the deprecation warnings.

Comment: What is in the Transcripts model file?

Comment: it seems to be complaining about `app/models/transcript.rb` - post the contents of the file as well pls

Comment: @Tonys: posted. It looks like it doesn't like the dependent: flag...odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model should look like this.

```
class Transcript < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :grade, :hours

  belongs_to :student, class_name: 'User', dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :course
end
```

What happened was that you didn't define `destroy` as a string or a hash. Hence why you got...

```
`destroy': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. Any ideas why it worked locally, but died spectacularly on the remote?

Comment: Not sure on that. Maybe someone with more knowledge can enlighten us. I would be interested to know why.