# Error deploying to Heroku (DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I get the following error when trying to push to Heroku. It works on localhost:3000 and not sure where to start. I removed the files in vendor/plugins (worked on localhost) but still produced the same error when trying to upload to Heroku.

```
C:\basecode>heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.9170
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support
for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them i
n your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initial
izers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonr
ails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required
)> at /app/Rakefile:4)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support
for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in 
your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initial
izers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonr
ails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required
)> at /app/Rakefile:4)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support
for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them i
n your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initial
izers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonr
ails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required
)> at /app/Rakefile:4)
==  CreateMicroposts: migrating ===============================================
-- create_table(:microposts)
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "microposts_id_seq" for serial         column "microposts.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "microposts_pkey" for   table "microposts"
-> 0.0521s
-- add_index(:microposts, [:user_id, :created_at])
-> 0.0462s
==  CreateMicroposts: migrated (0.0987s) ======================================
==  CreateRelationships: migrating ============================================
-- create_table(:relationships)
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "relationships_id_seq" for serial   column "relationships.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "relationships_pkey" for  table "relationships"
-> 0.0478s
-- add_index(:relationships, :follower_id)
-> 0.0440s
-- add_index(:relationships, :followed_id)
-> 0.0464s
-- add_index(:relationships, [:follower_id, :followed_id], {:unique=>true})
-> 0.0484s
==  CreateRelationships: migrated (0.1876s) ===================================
C:\basecode>heroku open
Opening nameless-tundra-1907... done
C:\basecode>
```

Comment: I hate this warning, and I would love to have a good answer for how to fix it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 2.3-style plugins and deprecation warnings running task in Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027403/rails-2-3-style-plugins-and-deprecation-warnings-running-task-in-heroku)

Comment: It's strange. When I was building the application I saved it in stages. When I try to upload it where it's stripped to basic user signup/login [here](http://floating-brook-8996.herokuapp.com) it seems to work so I know it's something in the later stage that is causing the error. Just not sure what?

Answer (score 6):

Remove your vendor/plugins/.gitkeep (if you have one)

```
git checkout master
git rm vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
```

Add these lines to you Gemfile

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Run the bundle command

```
bundle install
```

Commit your files Gemfile and Gemfile.lock

```
git add Gemfile Gemfile.lock
git commit -m 'Added gem rails_12factor to avoid warnings on heroku'
```

Push your changes and be free of these warnings forever

```
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to remove the plugin, you need to run `rails plugin remove [your-plugin]`, not just delete the folder.

Also, I believe heroku adds some plugins to your app, and it's possible that those are deprecated.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the need to run that command to remove the files so thank you. From what I can find heroku do inject plugins into the app (something that heroku themselves apparently admit is an issue) yet there does not seem to be any straight forward documentation to fix the problem. Maybe I will just rebuild the application in rails 4.0 and save myself the trouble.