# How can I solve these Rails deprecation warnings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems

I am getting the following deprecation warning:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released.

My two plugins are render_component and verification.  How should I go about bundling these as gems, or should I place them in another file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027403/rails-2-3-style-plugins-and-deprecation-warnings-running-task-in-heroku

Comment: I assume that you're upgrading your app from 2.3 to 3?